# checkers tiles not working properly

Tags: java

I'm working on a checkers assignment and even when I set it that only make the corresponding beige colours to glow green, the corner pieces still make the brown ones glow, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFggh.png

Here's the code for it:

```
for(int x=0; x<64; x++)
  {
    if (e.getSource()==board[x] && board[x].getText().equals("0") && board[x].getForeground().equals(Color.WHITE))
    {
        board[x].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        board[x-7].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        board[x-9].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        clickSteps=2;
      }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to take into account that `x-9` may not be one row up from where you are, if you are on the end of the row. Do you have to implement the board as a single-dimension array? It would be easier as a two-dimension array: board[][]

Comment: This code just seems to set the background color of `board[x]`, `board[x-7]` and `board[x-9]` - I can't see any logic that should "avoid" recoloring brown tiles... perhaps you can try to clarify what you are expecting and why?

Comment: @MattCoubrough So the point of my version of checkers is  that when you select the piece where you want to move, the valid places where you can go to will turn green. Sorry, I'm still a bit of a rookie in terms of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep `board` as a single dimension, this might work (untested):

```
for(int x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
    if(e.getSource() == board[x] &&
       board[x].getText().equals("0") &&
       board[x].getForeground().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
       board[x].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
       int myPos = x % 8;
       if(myPos < 7) {
          // Up and to the right, only if we are not rightmost.
          board[x-7].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
       }
       if(myPos > 0) {
          // Up and to the left, only if we are not leftmost.
          board[x-9].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
       }
    }       
}
```

Comment: being a complete rookie at this, may I ask how you figured that out?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you exactly, but the picture combined with the code sure helped.

Comment: I apologize for another question, but now it seems that every time I click a piece, -7 and -9 will always glow. I'm trying to make it so that only spaces with no pieces will glow green from -7 and -9 from the counter.